# Problem with updating object as a state, each update stores diff from init version of object

Tags: react-native

I have object with 2 props, each of it is an object with "value" prop and another prop which is callback to function for update the "value" prop.

Here is the full code:

```
export default function App() {

  const initObj = {
    name1: { 
      value: "",
      callback: func1
    },
    name2: { 
      value: "",
      callback: func2
    }
  }

  const [obj, setObj] = useState(initObj);

  function func1(val) {
    const newName1 = {...obj.name1, value: val};
    setObj({...obj, name1: newName1});
  }

  function func2(val) {
    const newName2 = {...obj.name2, value: val};
    setObj({...obj, name2: newName2});
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => obj.name1.callback("value1")}>setValue1</button>
      <button onClick={() => obj.name2.callback("value2")}>setValue2</button>
      <br/>
      {JSON.stringify(obj)}
    </>
  );
}
```

The result is as following.

```
First load:
{"name1":{"value":""},"name2":{"value":""}}

Click on button [setValue1]:
{"name1":{"value":"value1"},"name2":{"value":""}}

Click on button [setValue2]:
{"name1":{"value":""},"name2":{"value":"value2"}}
```

And so on. The Obj will never have `name1.value` and `name2.value` filled together.

Howewer, if I change code to this:

```
<button onClick={() => func1("value1")}>setValue1</button>
<button onClick={() => func2("value2")}>setValue2</button>
```

It will work. But this is not what I need. Later I want to send all props to components:

```
<Button {...Obj.name1} /> <Button {...Obj.name2} />
```

and this also won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the functions like below and try

```
  function func1(val) {
    const newObj = { ...obj };
    newObj.name1.value = val;
    setObj(newObj);
  }

  function func2(val) {
    const newObj = { ...obj };
    newObj.name2.value = val;
    setObj(newObj);
  }
```

Issue: Handling of closures and state updates in functional components in JS like here, when you define `func1` and `func2`, they capture the `obj` value from the initial render. So, when you call `func1` or `func2`, they use the `obj` value that was present at the time of their creation that is `initObj`, not the updated `obj` value.

Solution: Create a copy of `obj` as `newObj`, and then directly modify the `value` property of `newObj`. This approach works as expected because it doesn't rely on closures to capture the `obj` value, and it directly updates the properties.

Comment: It works, but doesn't it violates React principle not to mutate object in th state? newObj is not a full copy of obj. name1 and name2 still point to the same nested objects, so you directly modify it by newObj.name1.value = val

Comment: Here we're not directly mutating the state `obj`. Instead, we're creating a shallow copy of `obj` using the spread operator `{ ...obj }` and then modifying the `value` property of `newObj` then updating the state. So, in our code, modifying `newObj.name1.value` or `newObj.name2.value` does not violate React principles

Comment: I have made changes in my project. Seems to work anyway. Thank you! )